# Model-based reinforcement learning algorithms for continuous states and continuous actions

Tags: reinforcement-learning

Are there model-based reinforcement learning algorithms for continuous states and continuous actions? I was trying to find such algorithms but couldn't find any. I know dynamic programming is for discrete spaces only.

Thank you!